# Can all invited users check every apps uploaded by individual users in google play console?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Hi i have a doubt regarding the play console 
Can all invited users check every apps uploaded by individual users in play console?

I have multiple users to invite to google play console to upload their individual apps, but the apps uploaded by a user should not be visible to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely set credenctials for individual application one by one but I'm not sure if applications that user does not posses permission to edit etc. will be visible to him/her.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Pitor, I got the solution. Thanks for the support.

We can create draft apps and share those drafts with individual user